# Can't start system_health extended events session

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, extended-events

On some SQL Server instances, (I did not find a pattern yet), when I try to manually start this session, I get the following error :

> For target,
> "5B2DA06D-898A-43C8-9309-39BBBE93EBBD.package0.event_file", the
> parameter "filename" passed is invalid. Target parameter at index 0 is
> invalid (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 25641)

If we look into the SQL Server logs, each time the instance starts (i.e. after Windows reboots for patches to get applied), we get :

> Error: 25641, Severity: 16, State: 0. For target,
> "5B2DA06D-898A-43C8-9309-39BBBE93EBBD.package0.event_file", the
> parameter "filename" passed is invalid. Target parameter at index 0 is
> invalid
>
> Error: 25710, Severity: 16, State: 1. Event session
> "system_health" failed to start. Refer to previous errors in the
> current session to identify the cause, and correct any associated
> problems.
>
> Error: 25709, Severity: 16, State: 1. One or more event
> sessions failed to start. Refer to previous errors in the current
> session to identify the cause, and correct any associated problems.

Has anyone observed this issue ? I suspect it's due to permissions, as the definition of the session does not indicate a path, but simply the name of the .xel file. That is, it writes directly to the SQL Server logs folder, where obviously the SQL Server service account is granted full access.

I get the same issue for the AlwaysOn_health session.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: The files are sent to the default log path for the instance. You can recreate the XE session if needed: [recovery system health session](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3655/steps-to-recover-the-systemhealth-extended-events-session-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @Shawn That may have already been done (I suspect the sessions are being sent to a non-default place, as a problem with the default log path would also make writing the errorlog itself an issue). Easy to confirm how the sessions are configured.

Answer (score 5):

First, identify the folder that is the problem. In SSMS, with results set to grid, run the following query:

```
SELECT target_data = CONVERT(xml, target_data) 
  FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets
  WHERE target_package_guid = '5B2DA06D-898A-43C8-9309-39BBBE93EBBD'
  AND target_name = N'event_file';
```

Should return one row, and you should be able to click on it from the grid result. This will open a new tab with an XML document, which should look something like this:

```
<EventFileTarget truncated="0">
  <Buffers logged="0" dropped="0" />
  <File name="C:\...path_to_xe_files...\system_health_0_131278486394000000.xel" />
</EventFileTarget>
```

If the file name does not include a path component, the Extended Events default file location can be determined by looking in the system registry.  This code should do that:

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread
       @rootkey      = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
       , @key          = N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\CPE'
       , @value_name   = N'ErrorDumpDir';
```

Once you have the path where the Extended Events files are being saved, try to do something like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE model TO DISK = 'C:\...path_to_xe_files...\model_trash.bak'
  WITH INIT;
```

This should give you a better idea of what the problem is - could be permissions, could be that the folder doesn't exist (maybe the configuration for the instance was moved), could be a whole slew of things. But this should point you in the right direction and get you a better error message.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the very late answer. On the SQL Server (2014, 2016 and 2017) instances on which we have this issue, I ran the first query and did not get any row back. If I remove the WHERE clause, there are rows with router and ring_buffer targets, but there is no sign of event_file. Could this be an issue at installation time ?